# angular same height directive not working

Tags: angularjs

I have created a directive so that the columns in a bootstrap row are of same height.

Here is the code - http://jsbin.com/waxoboloqo/edit

But it is not working. Can you please fix it ?

Html code:

```
<h1>Height: {{ hei }}</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-1">
    <h1 ng-repeat="x in y" match-height>{{x}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-2">

  </div>    

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-lg-6 {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

Js:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.y = [1,2,3];
  $scope.hei = "initial"
})
.directive('matchHeight', function(){
  return function(scope, element) {
    if(scope.$last){
      scope.hei = $(element).height();
      $(element).closest(".row").find(
      ".col-2").height(scope.hei);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you expect col-2 height to be?

Comment: To be same as that of col-1

Comment: I mean the exact value! 36px, 39px or ...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
app.directive('getHeight',function () {        
      return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
      scope.$watch(function(){ 
        scope.style = {
            height:element[0].offsetHeight+'px', 
           // width:element[0].offsetWidth+'px'
          };
      });
        } 
      };
}); 

<div class="col-lg-6 col-1" get-height>
    <h1 ng-repeat="x in y">{{x}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-2" ng-style="style">

  </div>
```